# How to (custom size) write system equation in latex

Tags: equations, systeme

I can't solve write system equation custom size.

Code is here. But my system equation is big size like this image:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[mongolian]{babel}
\usepackage[b5paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath,array,amssymb,systeme}

\setlength{\parskip}{1.5em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.8}


\begin{document}

$
\begin{cases}
it's \ cases \ 1\\
sample 2
\end{cases} $
$\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
it's \ array \ 1\\
sample 2
\end{array} \right. 
$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do not use `\cases` enviroment?

Comment: Your code is correct. (I would honestly get rid of "l" in \begin{array}{rl}). It should work fine with concrete equations. Can you please specify what your problem is for the specific equations.

Comment: cases is same. and more size

Comment: @Altantsooj Tseveenjav: Why do you write `\displaystyle` in the inline mode `$...$`?

Comment: Cases does not below inside text style math, they should only be typeset in displayed form. You will be doing your readers a big disservice by typesetting it smaller and out of displayed form.

Comment: @MarianG.sorry my mistake

Comment: The code you post does _not_ yield the output you show. Please provide a _complete_ example showing the problem. Whatever is happening here is due to code you are withholding.

Comment: Can you tried this, please, in math-mode and not inline mode? See the difference: `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{cases}
\text{it's cases 1} &\\
\text{sample 2} &
\end{cases}\] 

\end{document}`

Comment: @Sebastiano it's a same

Comment: my header is

\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[mongolian]{babel}
\usepackage[b5paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

Comment: \usepackage{graphics,graphicx,paracol,colordvi,latexsym,
rotate, multicol,amsmath,array,longtable,amssymb,
enumerate,cancel,systeme}
\graphicspath{ {img/} }

\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
\usepackage{amsopn}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.5em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.8}

Comment: @AltantsoojTseveenjav Edit your question and, please, after you put the complete code. I see only the mix of packages.  As the best users have said compared to me, we can't help you.

Comment: Okay. sorry edited my question Mr @Sebastiano